# Panolens JS not outputting points to console

Tags: three.js

Using [Panolens JS](https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js), trying to get coordinates to output in the Console, however it is not working for me. I am holding CTRL as I drag mouse around and nothing appearing. Any one have suggestions?

```
<script src="https://pchen66.github.io/js/three/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://pchen66.github.io/js/panolens/panolens.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var panorama, viewer;

  panorama = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama( './img/test.jpg' );

  viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({output: 'console'});

  viewer.add( panorama );

</script>
```

[image: Image is loading fine. I also have another demo where I added a hotspot to random point and it works fine too.]

Comment: is your image loading correctly? can you view the image directly from your browser, from the same relative path?

Comment: I have included screenshot of image loading. Image is not the same exact path as if you find it in Chrome, but its the same image.. relatively the same path.. my current file structure is index.html, /img/test.jpg

Comment: do you have any other js libraries that could be interfering with or intercepting the keyboard `keydown` event from being handled correctly?

Comment: Nope, I did not include any other JS libraries, have also tried using incognito

Comment: very odd - sorry, no ideas coming to mind right now

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, be sure to add `output: 'console'` to your viewer options to output the raycast position in your browser console.